# How to remove an object in bge?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

I have the following piece of code to add an object to a scene in bge. When I use `endObject()`, the object disappears from the scene, but I can still see it in `scn.objects`. How can I remove it from `scn.objects`?

```
import bge
import bpy

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController( ) 

own = cont.owner
scn = bge.logic.getCurrentScene( )
ob = scn.addObject("Cube.001", "Empty", 0)
ob.endObject()

print(scn.objects) 

# the output is [Empty, Cube, Lamp, Camera, __default__cam__, Cube.001]
```

How can I remove `Cube.001` from that list?

Comment: Please do not mix bge and bpy code. These are APIs to two different applications.

Answer (score 2):

With [KX_GameObject.endObject()](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html?highlight=endobject#bge.types.KX_GameObject.endObject) you *request* the game object to be deleted.

This call does not remove the object from the scene at that time.

The object will be removed by the BGE after the actuators where executed. It takes effect within the next frame.

Imagine you put a label on the object ... "please remove" (or you put it in the trashcan). The janitor will remove it when cleaning the room.

**Remark**: It does not matter if you use endObject() or the EndObjectActuator. The behavior is the same.

Care the timing